# Open set, closed set or neither?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Is $P=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2: x>0, y\geq0\}$ open, closed or neither? Proof your claim.

For me thix exercise is really difficult because we just reviewed the concepts in class and then got this exercise. I know how to proof if something is an open set, so i have to find an r that for all ϵ>0 $B_ϵ(x_0,y_0)$ s.t. $|(x,y)-(x_0,y_0)|<r$. If I now would try to proof that it is open and I get that it is not open, have I then to proof that is closed? And if its not closed I can follow that it is neither? My guess would be that is neither but I find it really hard to proof it.

Comment: “Is it open?” and “is it closed?” are to separate questions. Just answer both, and you are done ;)  Do you think that the set is open? That it is closed? What would you have to do to show that it is not open? That it is not closed?

Comment: Does the point $(1,0)$ have a neighborhood contained in $P$? Does the point $(0,1)$ have a neighborhood contained in the complement of $P$? (Or the latter question for the point $(0,0)$ too?)

Answer (score 0):

To prove that set $P$ is open (or not) you must check wether (or not) you can find for every $(x_0,y_0)\in P$ an $\epsilon>0$ such that the set $B_{\epsilon}(x_0,y_0):=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\mid ||(x,y)-(x_0,y_0)||<\epsilon\}$ is a subset of $P$.

Can you find a suitable $\epsilon$ for $(1,0)\in P$?

If not then the conclusion is that $P$ is not open.

---

Proving that $P$ is closed (or not closed) is the same as proving that $P^c$, i.e. the complement of $P$, is open (or not open).

Can you find a suitable $\epsilon$ for $(0,1)\in P^c$?

If not then the conclusion is that the complement $P^c$ is not open, or equivalently that $P$ is closed.